# How can you use a single translation file in django?

Tags: django, translation

I have many django apps in a single project that all have translations. Many of these translations are repeated across the different apps. I struggle to keep the translations consistent and hence I would prefer a single file for all translations in all apps. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Can the downvoter take the effort to explain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Add the `locale_paths` to your settings as a single path. In my projects, I set it to something like that,

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

and use `python manage.py makemessages` (with proper settings specified if needed) and NOT the `django-admin makemessages` as it will give you issues with finding trans in your installed apps.

Finally, this will create a folder named `locale` in your project home directory with all the translations in it.

Hope this helps!